# При уменьшении ширины сайта переносится текст

Tags: html, css

При уменьшении ширины сайта переносится текст, как сделать так, чтобы он не переносился на другую строку а оставался как есть, как и в остальных блоках?
С мобильной версии получается вот так (present continuous):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтоб текст не сворачивался, можно добавить ему CSS-стиль `white-space: nowrap;`

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.text {
  width: 110px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #bbeecc;
  margin: 1em;
}

.text-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="text">Present continious</div>
  <div class="text text-wrap">Present continious</div>

</div>
```